# Javascript unterminated statements

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering how Javascript treats unterminated statements. I know that if an unterminated statements exists within an expression it will error out. Does anyone know of any resources that talk about how the Javascript compiler handles unterminated expressions/statements???

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unterminated"? A mid-token EOF?

Comment: Statements *never* exist within an expression.